# Using a ScarlaValue Function return value in another UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

`[CheckAtomicResultCriteria]` is a Scalar value function that returns a BIT.

I want to use that function in another TableValue function's where clause. Like below, but doesn't working. What is the correct way of using this?

```
WHERE [CheckAtomicResultCriteria](parameters) = '1'
```

Neither this works

```
WHERE (SELECT [CheckAtomicResultCriteria](parameters)) = '1'
```

Comment: What is the error message specifically? Are you prefixing your UDF with the schema (WHERE dbo.CheckAtomicResultCriteria(parms) = '1')

Comment: @Derek Kromm: Thank you for looking into this. Strange it works once I add dbo prefix. I am using a table value function in the same UDF without dbo prefix and that works fine. Do you have any idea? I could select your answer if you can post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing a UDF, you must prefix the schema.

So you need to call it like this:

```
WHERE dbo.CheckAtomicResultCriteria(parms) = '1'
```

Comment: In the same database, in the same UDF I am calling a different TableValueFunction successfully without specifying dbo prefix. Any idea?

Comment: A scalar valued function requires the schema prefix - table valued functions do not. Just the way it is.

Comment: I'll add that you should just ALWAYS prefix ALL objects with the proper schema prefix, regardless of what kind of object it is, or whether you are creating the object or just referencing it.